# How can I increase script space quota size of Firefox 3.6

Tags: firefox

Deserialization of 10000 domain objects causes `script stack space quota is exhausted` exception for firefox 3.6. Serialized stream size is about 2 mb.. I do not want suggestions like pagination, or another serialization scheme..

Is there any way to increase script stack space quota for firefox ?..

Answer (score 1):

Code splitting and runAsync(), within GWT 2.0, should resolve these issues.

Comment: Code splitting does not help in my case.. As I said, the problem occurs during deserialization of domain objects..

Comment: Can't you send JSON data and then convert them to the objects on the client side. If you cannot do that. I Will look at the the members of the class and see which shouldn't be serialized and which should and then give it a shot.

Comment: I am not using JSON, I am using gwt-rpc.. All necessary fields are serialized... The question is how to increase script stack quota of Firefox. If you have an answer to this question, I would accept your answer... I dont have any problem with chrome..

Comment: that's just the protocol but instead of returning the object, you can return JSON string which contains all the objects and then make the objects in onSucess() in the callback.  I had seen a bug  with the mozilla on the same issue.Does it work on IE ?

Answer (score 0):

Did not find something, either. Useful informations:

The bug-report:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=420869

A test to calculate the stack space limit:

http://entanglednetworks.com/foo